# How make anchor navigation list with asp mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, navigation

On my page there are a lot of records. It is a requirement for them to be displayed on a single place. But to make it easier to navigate we will add an index div that points anchors to some category.

For example we have category A B C D E and under a category there are products of that category

How do you make in ASP.NET MVC (anchor) link that point to the category  div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [named anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html):

```
<a href="#categoryA">Jump to category A products</a>
```

and somewhere else on the same page:

```
<div>
    <a name="categoryA">Category A products</a>
    ... some products here
</div>
```

The [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) is also worth checking out.